# How to call a function when two divs are "meet" using jQuery/JS?

Tags: jquery, html

below is a code that moves the big blue block through the screen. Also, in the screen there is a small red box "bomb". When those two are finally meet each other, how can I call a function or anything, like I need to write some lines or include a php file when this happen.

Thank you

A collide code can be found here http://vidasp.net/tinydemos/javascript-detect-overlapping.html , but how about on moving objects?

```
<html>
<head>
  <style>
.block {
  position:absolute;
  background-color:#abc;
  left:50px;
  width:90px;
  height:90px;
  margin:5px;
}
.bomb {
  position:absolute;
  background-color:red;
  left:550px;
  width:40px;
  height:40px;
  margin:5px;
}
</style>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <button id="left">left</button> <button id="right">right</button> <button id="up">up</button> <button id="down">down</button>

<div class="block"></div><div class="bomb"></div>

<script>
$("#right").click(function(){
  $(".block").animate({"left": "+=50px"}, "fast");
});

$("#left").click(function(){
  $(".block").animate({"left": "-=50px"}, "fast");
});

$("#up").click(function(){
  $(".block").animate({"top": "-=50px"}, "fast");
});

$("#down").click(function(){
  $(".block").animate({"top": "+=50px"}, "fast");
});

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I found it through stackoverflow and I thought that is a great example of what I want!

Comment: I'll look into your issue a bit later...

Comment: what about draggable and droppable objects, and just what you need in the http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Droppable#event-over event

Comment: Thank you Šime Vidas. @max4ever my goal it was to create a "path" for the div to go through it but I ended with this. What I mean draggable objects is not what I want for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just merged your and @Šime's code ..

have a look at http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/Z25aM/

Comment: Great, thank you! I was wondering if there is a way by having the position of the bomb (meaning left:200, top:100, right:300) to create a div that will "move" to this position and stop.

Comment: @Sampas, can you explain a bit more, because i am not sure i get what you want to do. Do you want the bomb to move ? (when should it start its move, and where should it go?)

Comment: Excuse me, let me explain it better. What we know is the position of the bomb. What we do, is to show a collision message when the .block hits the bomb. In next steps I will try to edit the code, so that the block will move automatically and randomly in the area until it finds the bomb. If i create two blocks that move in different directions through the area, is there any way the block that will collide the bomb to stop there, and the non collision block to move to the position where the bomb is ?

Comment: @Sampas, since you will be performing the collision tests per `.block`, you will know which element is the one that collides. At that moment you should issue a `.stop` command on its animation to make it stop moving..

Comment: Should I name the additional blocks to .block also ? Any modification to your existing fiddle would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Φίλε τώρα μόλις είδα ότι είσαι Έλληνας. Μπορείς να με βοηθήσεις σε παρακαλώ;

Comment: @Sampas let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1133/discussion-between-gaby-aka-g-petrioli-and-sampas)

Answer (score 0):

A good search term for you to research into is "collision detection"

Doing a quick search there is a jQuery game engine called "gameQuery" which may be of interest.

http://gamequery.onaluf.org/